# How do I serve my Node.js application on a subdomain?

Tags: node.js, port, subdomain, a-records

I have a web server running at `mydomain.com` and a Node.js application on a different server which I can get to through `111.111.111.111:8000`. I'd like to make this Node.js app available through my domain name, through a subdomain. That is, I want to be able to type in `node.mydomain.com` and have my traffic sent to `111.111.111.111:8000`. I thought this would be an easy job for an `A Record`, but it seems that I can only change the IP, not the port.

How would I accomplish this? I am assuming that I need to tell the VM running my Node.js application to accept traffic on port 80 and then redirect it to port 8000, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I know this is possible by using Apache or NGINX's `ReverseProxy` directives, but I'm sure there must be a simpler way through Node or some configuration on the VM.

Comment: "but it seems that I can only change the IP, not the port" can't you change the port you're running on instead if it's that easy?

Comment: I assumed that this would cause some problems since the Node app isn't a 'real' webserver like most things targeting port 80 would expect, but I'll try that right now. Don't know why it didn't cross my mind.

Comment: Express does not let me listen to port 80, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It's a real web server... Are there errors when you try to set it to port 80? Is it a restriction your host has?

Comment: It's mostly just that I'd rather not run Node.js as root, so the port needs to be above 1024.